# Which is correct, In which or In what...?

Tags: grammar

I refer, for example, to, "In which foods does one find carageenan?" vs. "In what foods...?" 
Thank you!

Comment: In which sounds like you already provided an array of options to choose from, whereas in what sounds like an open question.

Answer (score -1):

That depends on context. If it is understood that one is selecting from a specific list of foods, it would be "which". If the question is open-ended, it would be "what".

These two options make the choice clearer, because "of these" makes it obvious that one is selecting from a specific list:

1. In which *of these* foods does one find carrageenan?
2. In what foods does one find carrageenan?